# Как найти обьект в json vue.js, нужно ли переделывать обьект в массив?

Tags: json, vue.js

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Есть ссылка с данными
https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/all/coinlist?summary=true

Задача - найти обьект по полю Symbol и вывести его Symbol.

Не получается реализовать поиск через data2.find.
Нужно ли переделывать обьект в массив? или как баще сделать???

```
methods: {
    add() {
      const currentTicker = {
        name: this.ticker,
        price: '-',
      };
      this.tickers.push(currentTicker);
     
      let timerId2 = setInterval(async () => {
        const f2 = await fetch(`https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/all/coinlist?summary=true`);
        let data2 = [];
        data2 = await f2.json();
        //console.log(data2.Data['0XBTC'].FullName);
        console.log(data2);
        let searchSymbol = '0XBTC';
        let fullName = data2.find((symbol) => symbol['searchSymbol'] === searchSymbol).FullName;  
        }, 3000);
      setTimeout(() => {
        clearInterval(timerId2);
      }, 3000);

      this.ticker = '';
    },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сразу извиняюсь, если я что-то не так понял в Вашем вопросе, но почему нельзя использовать ключ в Data?

```js
const json = JSON.parse(`{
    "Data": {
        "42": {
            "Id": "4321",
            "ImageUrl": "/media/35650717/42.jpg",
            "Symbol": "42",
            "FullName": "42 Coin (42)"
        },
        "PRC": {
            "Id": "3638",
            "ImageUrl": "/media/20393/prc.png",
            "Symbol": "PRC",
            "FullName": "ProsperCoin (PRC)"
        }
    }
}`);

["42", "PRC", "RPC", "ABC"].forEach(function(elem){
  console.log(json?.Data[elem]?.FullName ?? `${elem} not found`);
});
```

И немного по Вашему коду. Следующие строки `let data2 = []; data2 = await f2.json();` можно сократить до `let data2 = await f2.json();`, т.к. после присвоения переменной data2 пустого массивы Вы перезаписываете его объектом.

Эта строка `data2.find((symbol) => symbol['searchSymbol'] === searchSymbol)` вводит меня в замешательство - у Вас-же нет свойства `searchSymbol`?! Или я что-то не так понимаю?

Comment: let data2 = []; пытался в массив поместить данные по ссылке

Comment: let data2 = await JSON.parse(f2); так не работает

Comment: как вы сделали из данных по ссылке обьект такого вида, вручную набрали для примера? 

 "Data": {
        "42": {
            "Id": "4321",
            "ImageUrl": "/media/35650717/42.jpg",
            "Symbol": "42",
            "FullName": "42 Coin (42)"
        },
        "PRC": {
            "Id": "3638",
            "ImageUrl": "/media/20393/prc.png",
            "Symbol": "PRC",
            "FullName": "ProsperCoin (PRC)"
        }
    }

Comment: @ЭддиВсё Вы-же сами привели ссылку с данными. Я просто оставил данные, которые относятся к Вашему вопросу. Мне кажется, что было бы излишним публиковать здесь JSON на несколько киллобайт. Если у Вас в переменной f2 находится текст в JSON-формате, то `let data2 = JSON.parse(f2);` должно работать.

Comment: я пытаюсь научиться, и все тщетно

Comment: @ЭддиВсё в таком случае решайте проблемы по мере их поступления. Конечно перед этим необходимо продумать как и что Вы будете делать. К примеру, так ли необходимо раз в 3 секунды посылать запрос на сервер? Насколько я понимаю на [бесплатном плане](https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/pricing) Вы быстро исчерпаете лимит в 100к запросов в месяц. Как минимум, нужно пересмотреть интервал запроса к серверу. Вполне возможно Вам не нужно запрашивать весь лист, если Вы всё равно его потом фильтруете. Полистайте [документацию](https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/documentation) к API.

Comment: думаете моя остановка не работает ? 

setTimeout(() => {
        clearInterval(timerId2);
      }, 3000);